# Trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 on iMac not working

Tags: system-installation, mac, 15.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 on my iMac 27". I use the full install .iso  with error checking returning positive with no errors on a PC, and bootable on PC, but the iMac gives me a lifeless, black screen. I see grub functioning, and when I try "Try Ubuntu without installing", You can see the usual "APCI probe failed" and another message given to me on PC, but caused no error whatsoever. Then, after that, the screen just turns off. Thats it. When I try "Install Ubuntu" The same things happen, but you can hear the bongoes when the screen goes off. And yes, I have tried the keys that usually start the backsplash and the text showing you what runs in the background. I think the mac is 3 years old.

Comment: You could try getting the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO, and if it works, upgrading to 15.04. I know how it feels having no one answer what seems to be an easy question, by the way.

Comment: Do I get Powerpc, or regular iso

Comment: yeh @Zacharee1 true dat

Comment: When is the Mac from?

Comment: My earlier 2013 27" imac works perfectly on 14.04.

Comment: Did you install rEFInd?

Comment: would that help the boot?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I heard installing 14.04 works  so i'll try that. I will also make a bootable powerpc, but they only have MATE. Whats that and howsit different?

Comment: Did you get Ubuntu 14.04 to install? I just finished installing on a 2007 iMac using 14.04.2. Do you know if you are booting in EFI mode or legacy BIOS mode?

Comment: @DavidAnderson ill try

Comment: @Zacharee1 post answer as told it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a PPC disc. It won't work PowerPC is the type of processor Macs used until Mac OS 10.4 was released. Your 2013 Mac is definitely an Intel, so you need to get the normal version, or it won't boot for sure.

P.S. -- this is what you meant right?